# python-docx correlating tables and paragraphs

Tags: python-docx

I've been successful in modifying a well structured source document using docx by examining styles and looking for text patterns.  Thanks to all who have developed and contributed.  One vexing problem I have is understanding where tables are at.  One of my needs is to delete an entire section of the doc.  Deleting the paragraphs gets the text and graphics but misses the tables.  My current table deletion routine relies on a knowledge of where in the document the tables live.  Is there a way to correlate the location of a table relative to the paragraphs (or some other element) around it?

Thanks,

-Chris

Comment: If you search (Google) on "python-docx iter_block_items" I think you'll find what you're after :)

Comment: Thanks scanny, appreciate your help on this and many past challenges!